# Conditional validation using Jquery doesn't work sometimes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have implemented Jquery Validator but facing issue with some conditional validation which is not working sometime.

1. I have requirement in which control should be required if radio button is selected for that I have created function which is called and I am passing radio button name to it.
2. I have faced this issue with other validation where a control is required only If any of the two radio button is selected out of 3.

When I add alert to function every time the alert gets called but validation doesn't
I have truncated my validation code Let me know If am I doing something wrong

Js Code:-

```
$('#ConditionalLiability').validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        ConcernsNoted: {
            required: true
        },
        ConcernsWithExteriorWalls: {
            required: ValidationRadio("ConcernsNoted", 'Y')
        },
        chkExteriorWalls: {
            required: ValidationRadio("ConcernsWithExteriorWalls", 'Y')
        },
        GranularLossComments: {
            required: Conditional("GranularLoss")
        }
    },
    showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var messages = "";
        var check = 0;
        $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
            check = 1;
            var id = $(value.element).attr('id');
            messages += (index + 1) + ". " + value.message + "\n";
        });
        messages = "Please correct following errors \n" + messages;
        if (check == 1) {
            alert(messages);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        SaveData();
    },
    messages: {
        ConcernsNoted: {
            required: "Please select a value for Concerns With Home Exterior"
        },
        ConcernsWithExteriorWalls: {
            required: "Please select a value for Concerns With Exterior Walls"
        },         
        chkExteriorWalls: {
            required: "Please select at least one option for Concerns with Exterior Walls"
        },
        GranularLossComments: { required: "Please enter comments for GranularLoss"
        }

    }
});


function Conditional(id) {
    var element = "input:radio[name='" + id + "']:checked";
    var radio_value = $(element).val();
    if ((radio_value == 'M') || (radio_value == 'S')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidationRadio(id, check) {
    var element = "input:radio[name='" + id + "']:checked";
    var radio_value = $(element).val();
    if (radio_value == check) {
        alert('true');
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you are passing the radio button ID, but you are looking up the radio buttons by name. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Sorry am passing name of radio button I have edited my question

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle? it would be helpful to see your html along with the javascript

Comment: Jsfiddle Link :- http://jsfiddle.net/3D8ce/6/  Its not working but added the html..

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle with different version of jquery validtor as am nt getting the online version of 1.11

Comment: For this to work, you also need to include the plugin in your code someplace.  Your jsFiddle does not include the jQuery Validate plugin at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.validate()` is the plugin's *initialization* method, however, [as per your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3D8ce/6/), you're calling it as if it was the method for testing form validity...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#submit').click(function () {
        submitForm();
    });
});

function submitForm() { 
    $('#ConditionalLiability').validate({
        // options & rules
    });
}

function Conditional(id) {
    // your code
}

function ValidationRadio(id, check) {
    // your code
}
```

Once initialized, the plugin *automatically* captures the click event of the submit button.

- Get rid of your `click` handler.  You do not need it, and in many cases, it interferes with the plugin's default behavior.

Also:

- Since you're using jQuery Mobile, use `.on('pageinit', function()` instead of `.ready(function()`
- Get rid of your broken external conditional functions and utilize the `depends` sub-option instead (see below).

Re-factor your code into this...

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {

    $('#ConditionalLiability').validate({
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            ConcernsNoted: {
                required: true
            },
            ConcernsWithExteriorWalls: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("[name='ConcernsNoted'][value='Y']").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            chkExteriorWalls: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("[name='ConcernsWithExteriorWalls'][value='Y']").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            GranularLossComments: {
                 required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                return ( $("[name='GranularLoss'][value='M']").is(":checked") || $("[name='GranularLoss'][value='S']").is(":checked") );
                    }
                 }
            }
        },
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            var messages = "";
            var check = 0;
            $.each(errorList, function (index, value) {
                check = 1;
                var id = $(value.element).attr('id');
                messages += (index + 1) + ". " + value.message + "\n";
            });
            messages = "Please correct following errors \n" + messages;
            if (check == 1) {
                alert(messages);
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            SaveData();
        },
        messages: {
            ConcernsNoted: {
                required: "Please select a value for Concerns With Home Exterior"
            },
            ConcernsWithExteriorWalls: {
                required: "Please select a value for Concerns With Exterior Walls"
            },
            chkExteriorWalls: {
                required: "Please select at least one option for Concerns with Exterior Walls"
            },
            GranularLossComments: {
                required: "Please enter comments for GranularLoss"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6GHKN/**

Comment: Thanks I already removed the function call but dint added the depends option will change it